# Webpack with multiple entry points and partial overlap

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, bundle

I have a rather complex folder structure because I have multiple language support and a folder for each language.

so I have something like:

```
themes/

  |base
  |desktop
  |mobile
  |de
  |en
  |es
```

the language folders share their JS/CSS with `base/desktop/mobile` but the folders themselves may have some custom CSS to add to that.

So the goal would be to have a single js bundle for `base/desktop/mobile` and have separate folders with CSS bundles for each language via the extract text plugin.

Is this possible with a single `webpack.config` file or would I have to do some black magic bundling each language separately and concat the js stuff together?

Do I have to come up with some webpack specific barrel files to bring it together or can I stay in default JS/CSS/HTML terms?

Answer (score 0):

you want to make one single bundled file for base/desktop/mobile?

why you don't make the css code with media query in single css file?

in other words, responsive design should cover your needed for base/desktop/mobile

Comment: For each of those I want to have a single bundle. So lets say base.js, desktop.js, mobile.js.
some languages have different styles for the same element for example. So the html may be the same but the css is different for example.